# Jekyll theme only works locally, not remotely

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-theme

I don't know how to solve this issue, people online had pointed out that it may have something to do with baseurl:, typing the name of my site there or leaving it empty doesn't seem to be working. People had also pointed out changing theme on the config.yml to "remote_theme", that also didn't work

Please have a look at my code, any ideas? I wish I had more information in regards to why this happens

Repo: https://github.com/SimonXTest/simonxtest.github.io

You'll know it's the right repo because there should be a broken.txt in the directory

Remote website image:

[image: Remote website image]

Local website image:

[image: Local website image]

Comment: Are you sure that your title is fine? It sounds for me the opposite: It works local == localhost, and NOT remote on github.io

Comment: @KargWare You are right, I typed the wrong title by accident.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to your GitHub workflow the `bundle-install` statement.
The rubygems (for the theme) are missing.

You don't have the `_layout` folder in your source control, so you need to get it from the gems.

In your GitHub Workflow / Action you should do something like this:

```yaml
jobs:
  bundler:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup Ruby
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          ruby-version: 3.0
          bundler-cache: true
          
      - name: Installing dependencies
        run: bundle install
```

Comment: how would I do this? I am not familiar with running and configuring workflows on github.

Comment: When I visit - https://simonxtea.github.io/ you **did** it. It works! In the code you have updated the workflow (githib action) the right way.

Comment: Oh no, sorry KargWare, I rolled back to a working version of my site. The broken version is now offline (the broken version uses the chirpy theme, not the default theme). The new repo is on https://github.com/SimonXTea/simonxtea.github.io-broken. Sorry, I should had updated you in the comments. The reason for this is that I want to keep working on the sites and the posts, since I want to use this website for job hunting, I can still bring back the broken version but only temporarily to fix this issue.  If this gets fixed, the broken version will be permanently online

Comment: I'll try the edit you made in your solution

Comment: It's still not working, I edited the file called "pages-deploy". Please see here https://github.com/SimonXTea/simonxtea.github.io/blob/main/.github/workflows/pages-deploy.yml, the file should say "#Hi KargWare" to let you know that you are on the right repo (if it doesn't say that, try https://github.com/SimonXTea-broken/simonxtea-broken.github.io/blob/main/.github/workflows/pages-deploy.yml)

Comment: The error I get is "Gemfile not found". After I got that error, I tried running "BUNDLE_GEMFILE="Gemfile" bundle install" instead. This also didn't work, I get this error when I do that: [!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /home/runner/work/simonxtea.github.io/simonxtea.github.io/Gemfile. Bundler cannot continue.
Error: Process completed with exit code 4.